# Passing a read-only parameter in C++: copy or reference, or

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have a template function, that accepts a read-only parameter of the templated type. This is a library function for various platforms, from 8-bit (AVR8) to 32 bit (Cortex). How to pass this parameter?

```
template< typename T >
void f( const T p ){ ... }

template< typename T >
void f( const T & p ){ ... }
```

By value is (probably) more efficient for parameter types that are smaller than a pointer, by reference is (probably) more efficient for parameter types that are larger than a pointer, and/or expensive to copy.

Is there any standard way to abstract this choice, like

```
template< typename T >
void f( pass_efficiently< T > p ){ ... }
```

?

Comment: I believe on most systems placing value in a register is a single operation, no matter if the length is shorter or equal to the length of the register.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with this.  The possible little bit of performance you save  is not worth having to duplicate every function based on if it is small or large.  That adds a lot more maintenance cost to a project.

Comment: For one single function I might not bother with this, but it is a fundamental problem that occurs over and over in the libraries I write (sometimes with multiple parameters). I think a reasonable solution is not *that* complicated, so I hoped for someone to have solved this for me.

Comment: Don't bother about that. Read-only: pass const T&. The compiler will know how to treat it efficiently. Always keep in mind that compilers are very smart.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::is_fundamental` to check if the value is a built in type and overload/specialize to pass by value if true.

There are more things to specialize for using the type support library `<type_traits>`
such as  `is_enum`, `is_trivially_copyable`, `is_array` and many more. I would recommend checking it out and seeing what works best for you.

Reference link for `std::is_fundamental` :
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental
Reference link for `<type_traits>`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns false for pointer types, which are likely better passed by value than by reference.

Comment: You might want to use the size of the type instead.  This wont pick up things like an enum or small classes.

Comment: My idea was indeed to specialize on the size of the type. I think at the user side that boils down to either pass< t >::t (ugly) or the same wrapped in a macro (ugly). I was hoping for someone to have found a better solution.

Comment: I think it's not worth it to use std::is_fundamental. Just pass const T&. The compiler will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from Bryan's answer and your additional question, hopefully to make it clear:

You can compose a type trait using Bryan's information and, if you want, the size. For this example, I'm using `std::is_trivially_copyable` and an implementation-defined maximum size:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_efficiently_copyable_v =
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && (sizeof(T) <= magic_size);
```

Then, you can use this trait to define which function to use with SFINAE (or concepts in C++20), making them mutually exclusive:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(const T&) -> std::enable_if_t<!is_efficiently_copyable_v<T>>;

template <typename T>
auto f(T) -> std::enable_if_t<is_efficiently_copyable_v<T>>;
```

(You can also use any other flavor of SFINAE you want)

This way, your function `f`'s interface always receives the parameter in your desired way. [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/XHMbpl): Notice which functions are called in the assembly output.

---

Just a small side note: GCC generates the same code for `const T&` and `T` parameters in all architectures I tested, but Clang doesn't, so beware of that if you just want to go the const reference route. [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/_DrP2o): you may change the parameter type in the `main` function and between compilers to verify this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't scale up well to multiple parameters. But it can trivially be converted to fast_copy< T >::t , which could be hidden behind a macro.

Comment: "GCC generates the same code for const T& and T parameters" I hope it doesn't do that things that have a cpopy constructor: passing a ref should never invoke the copy constructor!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Fair point about the scaling. I don't think there's a way to implicitly construct a type that depends on T in the parameter of the function (see std::forward implementation, for example, that requires explicitly naming T), otherwise that would be very easy to do what you need. And, by the code generated by GCC, I mean each function's code. The copy constructor is called before the object is put on the registers/stack.

Comment: I checked GCC for avr8. It definitely generates worse code for const uint8_t & than for a plain cont uint8_t.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen yes, if you change the version of the code I linked from GCC 5 to GCC 10, you'll notice the function size increases for my example, as well. I believe they changed the ABI from GCC 9 to 10, for how function parameters are passed.